# Arch/Tint2/OpenBox Displaying boxes instead of text

Tags: linux, text, openbox, tint2

I have a fresh Arch setup with the following installed:

- `xterm`
- `openbox`
- `tint2`

Now after starting `tint2`, the panel in the lower left-hand corner displays what seems to be a working panel, but with boxes instead of text:

[image: tint2 panel]

What I think is a related problem is menus that have no text inside them at all, yet has working links:

[image]

I suspect this has something to do with `openbox`, but it could be Arch itself or even `tint2`.

I should also note that I get errors when starting `tint2`, a whole lot of "Could not open file" referring to applications that don't even exist on my system such as `firefox.desktop`, `iceweasel.desktop`, `chromium-browser.desktop`, and `google-chrome.desktop`. There are also errors loading icons, which I assumed would have come bundled with the `tint2` install. Two lines read:

> tint2: Loading additional icon themes (this means your icon theme is incomplete)...
>
> tint2: Could not find icon 'application-x-executable', using default.

Another error later on, possibly related:

> tint2: pixmap background detection failed

Some other errors:

> tint2: No XSETTINGS manager, tint2 uses config option 'launcher_icon_theme'.
>
> tint2: Loading config file: /home/jeremy/.config/tint2/tint2rc

Comment: Those empty boxes and menus usually mean that you don't have suitable fonts installed.  Please include the output of `pacman -Q|grep xorg-fonts`.

Comment: The `tint2` errors are unrelated to the font problem, and deserve a separate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those empty lines and boxes are what are displayed when X applications can't find a suitable font.  You can test whether any fonts are available by running `fc-list`.

In Arch, there's no default font package.  Installing `xorg-fonts-misc` will be enough to make OpenBox and Tint2 usable:

```
pacman -S xorg-fonts-misc
```

The resulting text may be quite basic (fixed-width).  Packages that provide proportional fonts include `xorg-fonts-type1`, `ttf-bitstream-vera`, and `ttf-dejavu`.